# python sqlite3 not working

Tags: python, sqlite

```
try:
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("insert or replace into registrations values " +
              "(?, ?, datetime('now'))", (user, identity))
    print '\t<update>true</update>'
except Exception,inst:
    print inst.args
```

insert create table not working. How do I fetch the exception details?

Comment: First off, please use code blocks for the code, it would make it much easier to read. Ctrl-K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read this Python [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), it should describe the exception classes for the Sqlite Python module.

Have you tried something like this:

```
try:
  db_cursor.execute('some hopefully valid SQL;')
except sqlite3.Error, msg:
  print msg
```

Comment: thnx a ton JAN... i found out the following error..unable to open database file.. can u help me on this

Comment: Having being pissed for a while, I finally figured out what was wrong here: The web server needs the write permission to not only the database file, but also the containing directory of that file.